# non-coding RNA modelling in silico

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, splicing, noncoding-rna

I've been trying to model a non-coding RNA molecule which binds to a RNA binding protein. I found the DNA sequence for ncRNA from NCBI. I did not find the RNA seq of the same. Hence my doubt is, whether we should take the DNA seq and convert all the thymidine to uridine and then take that sequence for RNA modelling. Also, I wanted know if there is any kind of splicing occurring in case of ncRNA formation. Thank you in Advance.